# Retrieve SharePoint File Associations Icons programatically

Tags: file-icons, development, web-part

[This article explains](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837849) how you can configure icons for files in SharePoint. But what if you want to reuse these icons for custom links that your solution (e.g. webpart) generates. Is there a smart and easy way to read these Mappings to determine icon for each URL pointing to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and an API exists to help you!

SPUtility's following method can retrieve the value of the icon for the file (or file extension) that you specify in input parameter.

```
public static string MapToIcon(
    SPWeb web,
    string strFileName,
    string strProgID,
    IconSize size
)
```

Notes:
1. The returned value is based on the mapping between file extension and corresponding icon that exists in {SharePointRoot}\TEMPLATE\XML\DOCICON.XML

1. Icon needs to be present in {SharePointRoot}\Template\Images folder

The value that you might be interested would be /_layout/images/[Returned Value of above function]

Comment: Huh, now that you mentioned that, I also fond this nice article about that: http://www.bwaretech.com/en/Community/Team_Blog/EntryId/12/SPUtility-MapToIcon-vs-SPFile-IconUrl.aspx

Comment: Nice article. Good Luck to you!